# How to copy RCA PEM file from RCA to ICA?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to deploy Hyperledger Fabric in a automatized way and I am having some problems with certificates. My point is that, once the PEM file is created in the RCA though the command `fabric-ca-server init`, I want it to be shared to the Intermediate CA (as far as I have seen, it is required to run everything in a secure way). However, all the ways of doing it I am founding require me to scp the PEM file from RCA to my desktop and scp again the same file from my desktop to the ICA.

Isn't there a roundabout for it? I would not like to copy manually the file or using a shared space because nodes are not in the same physical computer and something like NFS would not be secure. I am looking for something like an API call (with the RCA username and password) that would solve it.

Also, I am actually new to certificates and do not know if PEM files have to be/are regenerated periodically. I am asking it because perhaps I have to check and copy this file with some frequency.

Thank you very much

Comment: are you using docker or nodes are setup on individual server ?

Comment: @mohammedrampurawala I am using Docker over Kubernetes

Comment: you can try docker secrets, create docker secret for cert file than mount that secret in docker container of ICA. but you still need to copy cert from RCA

Comment: Thanks for your help but that does not solve anything at all. It is exactly what I said I do not want to do.